# Can't remove ListView item in tornadoFX

Tags: tornadofx

There is two listview, I can drag an item into another, but the dragged item won't be deleted from the source list.

I know the code is not the right way to handle data, however I think it should work, but it just don't.

```
     ...
    setOnDragDone {event ->
       removeSelected(event.gestureSource)
    }
    ...
    fun  removeSelected(gestureTarget: Any?) {
        var listview = gestureTarget as ListView<String>
        val modelItems = FXCollections.observableList(listview.selectionModel.selectedItems)
        if (modelItems != null) {
            listview.selectionModel.clearSelection()
            listview.items.removeAll(modelItems)
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overthinking this and introducing some traps for yourself along the way :)

You create the `modelItems` list as an observable list, backed by the ListView's selectedItems property. So changes to the selected items in the ListView will be reflected in your `modelItems` property.

When you call `selectionModel.clearSelection()`, your `modelItems` list is also empty, so you're calling `removeAll(anEmptyList)`.

Just do `listview.items.removeAll(listview.selectionModel.selectedItems)`. The ListView will update the selected items list when the items are removed from the backing list.

Comment: `listview.items.removeAll(listview.selectionModel.selectedItems)`  gets a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`,  even if the clearSelection() is commented out, it still doesn't remove.

Comment: I create the copy of selected items due to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132896/listview-removeall-doesnt-work, I am not sure if this still necessary.

Comment: This would indicate that your list bound to the listview.items function is not mutable. How do you assign the items? Try to assign FXCollection.observableArrayList<String>() to `listview.items` when you create it.

Comment: THANK you sir, it works, did not realize the list is immutable.

Comment: My pleasure :) That would depend on how you defined the list, but generally you should work with observable mutable data structures in JavaFX IMO.